What is a concise equivalent or synonym for the idiom "Shooting one/him/herself in the foot" in context of this dialogue between mother and daughter?
I am, ideally, looking for concise phrases and terms that are equivalent in meaning (i.e., synonyms) for an English idiom. The English idiom is "Shooting oneself in the foot."
To include information on how this word will be used in order to be answered, please see the following dialogue as an example:
Shooting Herself in the Foot

Mom: But, this is exactly how you start a fight with someone that you need in your life and who you really care about. Then, you hurt them and lose them. Paul is so sweet and perfect. What were you
thinking?
Daughter: grunts
[…]
Daughter: Yes! Like, will he will stop talking to me forever--what do I do?
Mom: There's nothing you can do if he blocked you and isn't answering your calls.
Daughter: what do I do?!
Mom: I'll call him, sweetie. That's all I can do for now.
[…]
Mom: I know how irritated you get. You just need to learn to control yourself and pick and choose your battles. Else, you will be
shooting yourself in the foot. Paul was perfect.
Daughter: You're right!
Mom: He was such a lovely young man. You shouldn't have done that.
Daughter: MOM, I know. Help!
Mom: He was trying to help you. You need him. And you pushed him away and hurt him. You need to take accountability for your actions and apologize. He was SO good to you.
Daughter: I KNOW! Stop rubbing it in.
Mom: I just need to make you understand so you don't make this mistake again. We don't even know if he will talk to me now.
Daughter: You're right, mom! I feel so bad.
Mom: Bad for you or bad for him?
Daughter: Both!
[…]
Mom: Next time, make sure you don't hurt the people who help you. You need them. That would be shooting yourself in the foot.
[…]
Her mother smiled warmly and Krysten rolled up her sleeves and started drying the washed dishes as her mom passed them to her. She understood why she had shot herself in the foot.


"Shooting oneself in the toe." already seems fairly concise. What specifically are you hoping for in an alternative?

Perhaps, one large word, I would use a word like self-sabotage.

Surely you mean shoot oneself in the foot. Toe is completely unidiomatic.

Please give the context, in a sentence, that demonstrates how you will use this.. PS it is usually, to shoot oneself in the foot.

Your "self-sabotage" makes it sound like a deliberate action, which is not conveyed by the idiom "shoot onself in the foot". See Farlex. A verb could be trip up.

@WeatherVane Yes, the sense of the expression has changed since its origin that relates to WW1. Sometimes Soldiers wishing to leave the front deliberately injured themselves in order to be evacuated. Shooting yourself in the foot caused an inability to move and therefore was enough to be repatriated for war injuries.

'Hoisting oneself with one's own petard' is neither more concise than your [intended] expression nor a particularly common variation on the original quote from Shakespeare. But it is a synonym.

@Graffito — That wasn't an idiom back then; it referred to literally shooting one’s foot.

Next time, make sure you don't hurt the people who help you. You need them. That [action] could backfire on you

Try and express it literally. Something like (only) hurting yourself. Don't expect people to read the entire dialog.

Per @Greybeard, "Please give the context, in a sentence" meant a short example would have helped. Short.

The extract is unnecessarily long

@Mari-LouA Why is stack exchange so full of critics? too short or too long, too general or too specific! And, now, I am not perfect, but, being an advanced/expert native speaker, I am still being critiqued!

I'm sorry, but you can rollback the edit. Although I think for context and for users to get an idea of  what you need, this is enough. Again, I'm sorry if the edit offended you, it was not my intention.

Far, far too long.
Why should readers suffer because you can't reduce all that stuff?
Either way, to 'shoot yourself in the foot has one clear meaning'… that being to inflict an injury on oneself, in hope of being sent home alive from a war zone
The phrase has a secondary, rather unlikely, meaning of 'thwart your own ambitions/goals/targets…' which I hope is only ever used by people not understanding the primary meaning…

“ Moore got a .25 automatic handgun and tried to shoot the snake, but shot herself in the toe instead, Rodgers said.” Sometimes it just means what it says.

Wiktionary gives the definition “to act against one’s own interests,” which seems serviceable if you are looking for a literal phrase, and suggests “dig one’s own grave” or “foul one’s own nest” as synonyms. I can’t say I have ever heard the second one, but I think the meaning of both idioms is pretty readily apparent.
